# How to determined if the user touch my bitmap?

Tags: java, android, canvas, bitmap, ontouchlistener

How to determine if the user clicked in certain regions of my ImageView?

I'm having a little bit of difficulty setting the (x,y) coordinate bounds to detect when a particular bitmap is being clicked on or not.

For example if the bitmap's position is (75,75),say. i.e. top left corner is at this point, then if the user touches the screen at point (X,Y), then the simple conditional:

I have 4 image position that i draw in canvas it's (75,75),(645,75),(1215,75) and (75,490).

it wasn't able to determined what i click it always give me message, "mImaget" instead of the others.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

             if (x >= 75 && x < (75 + mImaget.getWidth())
                    && y >= 75 && y < (75 + mImaget.getHeight())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mImaget", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("TOUCHED", "X: " + x + " Y: " + y + mImaget.getWidth() + "-" + mImaget.getHeight());
            }

            if (x >= 645 && x < (645 + mImageth.getWidth())
                    && y >= 75 && y < (75 + mImageth.getHeight())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mImageth", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("TOUCHED", "X: " + x + " Y: " + y + mImageth.getWidth() + "-" + mImageth.getHeight());
            }

            if (x >= 1215 && x < (1215 + mImagef.getWidth())
                    && y >= 75 && y < (75 + mImagef.getHeight())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mImagef", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("TOUCHED", "X: " + x + " Y: " + y + mImagef.getWidth() + "-" + mImagef.getHeight());
            }

            if (x >= 75 && x < (75 + mImageo.getWidth())
                    && y >= 490 && y < (490 + mImageo.getHeight())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mImageo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("TOUCHED", "X: " + x + " Y: " + y + mImageo.getWidth() + "-" + mImageo.getHeight());
            }

            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Thankyou :)

Comment: Are you drawing bitmaps on canvas or setting in layouts?

Comment: Yes, i draw it in canvas and put it in imageview like this: imageview.setImageBitmap(mBackground);

Comment: Can you set setOnClick or setOnTouchListener() on imageview object ?

Comment: yes, i did but there's something wrong with my condition of x and y i just want to determined if i touch a certain regions of the 4 position :) can you please read my question thankyou.

Comment: `I have 4 image position that i draw in canvas`, what is your drawing code (`onDraw`) ?

Comment: i add my canvas please see my edit.

Comment: read about `ImageView#getImageMatrix` and study carefully *the whole* `Matrix` API

Comment: where should i put that? in onTouch?

Comment: one last question, but the position top and left is also my x and y? in ontouch if i use matrix?

Comment: try to map the point [0,0] or [75, 75] or [645, 75], what is the result of mapping?

Comment: I'm trying something like this- but stil it's not giving my current x and y. Matrix inverse = new Matrix();
mage_one.getImageMatrix().invert(inverse); float[] pts = {event.getX(), event.getY()};
                inverse.mapPoints(pts);

Comment: it gave me a float value, but i dunno what should i put in my condition now.

Comment: great! and what is pts now? is `inverse` an identity matrix?

Comment: just `Log.d` pts[0] and pts[1]

Comment: yes, i did it now. should i change my x now to pts[0]?  if (pts[0] >= 75 && pts[0] < (75 + mImaget.getWidth())
                    && pts[1] >= 75 && pts[1] < (75 + mImaget.getHeight())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "mImaget", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                Log.e("TOUCHED", "X: " + x + " Y: " + y + mImaget.getWidth() + "-" + mImaget.getHeight());
            }

Comment: stil the same :( it's not working.

Comment: is `inverse` an identity matrix? try to log it with `Log.d`

Comment: yes, inverse is matrix. :( till now nothing's changed. Matrix{[1.0, 0.0, 0.0][0.0, 1.0, 0.0][0.0, 0.0, 1.0]}

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int x = (int) event.getX();
    int y = (int) event.getY();
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:

            if (x >= 75 && x < (75 + mBack.getWidth())
                    && y >= 75 && y < (75 + mBack.getHeight())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Zone1: " + x +"-" + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (x >= 645 && x < (645 + mBack.getWidth())
                    && y >= 75 && y < (75 + mBack.getHeight())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Zone2: " + x +"-" + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (x >= 1215 && x < (1215 + mBack.getWidth())
                    && y >= 75 && y < (75 + mBack.getHeight())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Zone3: " + x +"-" + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            if (x >= 75 && x < (75 + mBack.getWidth())
                    && y >= 490 && y < (490 + mBack.getHeight())) {
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Zone4: " + x +"-" + y, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            Log.d("TOUCHED", "X: " + x + " Y: " + y + mImaget.getWidth() + "-" + mImaget.getHeight());


            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Could you please try this one part of code instead your example.

Comment: Hi, i'm sorry can you please my edit. it was not mBack.

Comment: same it's not working, the condition always go to Zone1